# HTML DOM - spreading the string to multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm currently trying to spread the string to multiple lines at HTML/JS. I'm using Repl.It (maybe it some bug/feature on this page) but I cannot spread it to multiple lines using "\n". Please advise.

HTML div:

```
<div id="stats"> 
<script src="script.js"></script>
</div>
```

JS side:

```
function send_stats(message) {
  document.querySelector("#stats").innerHTML = message;
}

send_stats("Stats:\nPlayer hp:" + player_hp + "\nMonster hp:" + monster_hp")
```

Comment: `\n` is a *JavaScript* string escape code. `.innerHTML` is for parsing strings using the *HTML* parser, so you need to use an HTML solution... `<br>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `<br>` instead of `\n`. And use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) rather than using `+` again and again.

```js
let monster_hp = 100.00
let player_hp = 90.00
function send_stats(message) {
  document.querySelector("#stats").innerHTML = message;
}
send_stats(`Stats:<br>Player hp:${player_hp}<br>Monster hp:${monster_hp}`)
```

```html
<div id="stats"> 
<script src="script.js"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.innerText` instead of `innerHTML`

```js
var playerHp = 1;
var monsterHp = 30;
var msg = "Stats:\nPlayer hp: " + playerHp + "\nMonster hp: " + monsterHp;


function sendStats(sel, msg) {
  document.querySelector(sel).innerText = msg;
}

sendStats('#stats', msg);
```

```html
<output id='stats'></output>
```

Comment: `.innerText` is non-standard. Use `.textContent` instead.

Comment: @ScottMarcus [*"This feature was originally introduced by Internet Explorer, and was formally specified in the HTML standard in 2016 after being adopted by all major browser vendors."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText#Browser_compatibility) . Its been standard for over 2 years.

Comment: The quotes is referring to the the [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute) Spec. It's not in the [W3C DOM API](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent) and so, although it is supported, it's not standard. There are APIs where the two specs. diverge and it's generally best to use what's in the W3C spec. Also, it works differently than the standard (`textContent`) does.